# jinja: How to get max of two values

Tags: flask, jinja2

in a list pagination, I want to render the current page with two pages before and after it, providing it's not zero or one. I tried:

```
    {% for p in range(max(1, list.cur_page - 2), min(list.cur_page + 2, list.pages)) %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ list.url }}/{{ p }}">{{ p }}</a></li>
```

But it doesn't recognize min and max, I know that there is a filter named min max but how can I apply it here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems I can use `min` and `max` filters in `range` parameters,

```
range([list.cur_page - 2, 2] | max, ...)
```

so I have:

```
{% if list.pages > 1 %}
  <ul class="pagination float-start flex-wrap ms-5">
    {{ render_button(list, 1) }}
    {% for p in range([list.cur_page - 2, 2] | max, [list.cur_page + 3, list.pages - 1] | min ) %}
    {{ render_button(list, p) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ render_button(list, list.pages) }}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```